# Incompatible types inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)

Tags: java, generics, retrofit, retrofit2

So I have a model `Model`.

```
public class Model { .... }
```

This has two subclasses:

```
public class SubmodelA extend Model { .... }
```

and

```
public class SubmodelB extend Model { .... }
```

These three are wrapped under `Data` class.

```
public class ApiData<T extends Model> {

    public T data;

}
```

My general `response wrapper` looks like this:

```
public class ApiResponse<DATA> {

    DATA data;
}
```

The "dummy" api operation remains the same:

```
public interface Endpoints {

    Call<ApiResponse<ApiData>> getData();
}
```

I have an implementation of `retrofit2.Callback` to handle the responses:

```
public class ApiCallbackProxy<T> implements retrofit2.Callback<T> {

    public interface ApiResultListener<RESPONSE_TYPE> {
        void onResult(RESPONSE_TYPE response, ApiError error);
    }

    private ApiResultListener<T> mListener;

    private ApiCallbackProxy(ApiResultListener<T> listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<T> call, Response<T> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t) {

    }

    public static <T> ApiCallbackProxy<T> with(ApiResultListener<T> callback) {
        return new ApiCallbackProxy<>(callback);
    }
}
```

The ApiClient

```
public class ApiClient {

    public Endpoints mRetrofit;

    public ApiClient() {
       Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().build();
       mRetrofit = retrofit.create(Endpoints.class);
    }

    public <U extends Model> void getData(ApiResultListener<ApiResponse<ApiData<U>>> callback) {
       //Compiler hits here
       mRetrofit.getData().enqueue(ApiCallbackProxy.with(callback));
    }
}
```

Compiler hits at `ApiCallbackProxy.with(callback)` with this error:

[image]

So I want depending on where this API call is used in the app to return a different subclass of model or the model itself.

ie.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient();
    apiClient.getData(listener2);
}


public static final ApiResultListener<ApiResponse<Data<SubmodelA>>> listener = (response, error) -> {};

public static final ApiResultListener<ApiResponse<Data<Model>>> listener2 = (response, error) -> {};

public static final ApiResultListener<ApiResponse<Data<SubmodelB>>> listener3 = (response, error) -> {};
```

Comment: What is `ChallengeData`?

Comment: I mean `Payload` :) I changed the actual names to more generic ones.

Comment: I see, I think you still have a few more errors like that. Would be nice if you could post a [mcve]

Comment: @Manos can you add the declaration code for the field ```mRetrofitApiInterface``` and at least an extract of the enclosing class including its signature (name, type-parameters, super class/interface list...) and key field/methods. Thanks.

Comment: This is just the result of `Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()`,  `mRetrofitApiInterface = retrofit.create(Endpoints.class);'

Comment: @Manos looking at the latest Retrofit 2.x javadocs ```Retrofit.Builder``` does not have a ```create``` method but ```Retrofit``` itself does, so you mean to say that the value in ```mRetrofitApiInterface``` is the result of a ```retrofit.create(Endpoints.class)``` call where ```retrofit``` is typed ```Retrofit``` and not ```Retrofit.Builder```?

Comment: @Manos  In any, can you simply state what is the type of the ```mRetrofitApiInterface``` field? The prefix ```m``` is typically use for fields and not temporal/local variables so that is why I'm assuming that it is a field. If such type includes a type-parameter I would like you to also add the signature of the enclosing class. You can edit/improve your question with those details rather than provide them in a comment.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer this if you'd provide a [mcve]. Something we can compile with no other dependencies, and see the error.

Comment: Could you add declaration for ApiResponse ?

Comment: I proposed one more solution, but I can't but agree with @JonSkeet that the question is done quite poorly, e.g. leaving out class definitions, which can be crucial. I think I found the solution, but I had to use naming like "unknown class" for those. What I don't get is who gave this guy so many upvotes on such a poorly written question.

Comment: You're correct that the question is poorly written. I will try to re-write it.

Comment: Question is edited.

Comment: Well, your use of generics is plain wrong, so it makes it a bit hard to tell what exactly needs to be done. The way you're using ApiData in interface `Endpoints`, without giving it any concrete type, is just wrong, and I mentioned it in my answer (I'll update it to include the now mentioned class names).

Answer (score 6):

The `ApiClient` class has a listener that expects `ApiData<U>` in the response.

The problem is, there is no `U`. You have an `Endpoint`, and the endpoint has no generic types, and it returns just `ApiData` with no concrete type selected for the generic.

This is a case of generics gone wrong. The usual idea would be to make Endpoint generic:

```
public interface Endpoints<U> {
    Call<ApiResponse<ApiData<U>>> getData();
}
```

---

However, what does the `Retrofit` do? It turns HTTP API into Java interface. And looking at [the most simple example at the github repo of Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), it seems pretty clear to me that you are supposed to put interfaces that access some real HTTP endpoint. It is not some abstract `GET`.

So you'd rather give it a concrete type than make it generic. Do something like:

```
public interface Endpoints {
    Call<ApiResponse<ApiData<Model>>> getData();
}
```

I expect Retrofit to deserialize the data in the response to your `Model`. So, having a concrete class rather than an unset generic type variable is crucial to the successful deserialization. However, you can only use it with listeners being either of the following:

```
ApiResultListener<ApiResponse<Data<Model>>>
ApiResultListener<ApiResponse<Data<? super Model>>>
```

---

*Also, in the older part of the question, the `ApiResponse<Payload>` part where the generic type variable looks like it was `Payload` class, now that is quite devious :)*

Comment: Is it wise though to make the Retrofit service interface a generic interface? How am I going to instantiate it ? `mRetrofit = retrofit.create(Endpoints.class);`

Comment: @Manos I edited the answer after reading the most basic example on Retrofit. What you are doing wrong is, your `Endpoints` is some abstract class (I still find the plural gross, but w/e) that does a `GET /data` on some unspecified HTTP address, with unspecified data type returned. This part is where it goes wrong - you need to give it some concrete type that corresponds to the REST endpoint you call. I called it `MyDummyClass` in the answer.

Comment: For the purposes of the question, retrofit doesn't affect anything. I just happened to experience the error while working with it. That why I didn't provide a `@GET` or `@POST` annotation because it's simply irrelevant. Also, introducing a new class seems redundant to me, since the hypothetical HTTP Request returns an `ApiData<Model>`. I can't really understand why something like `Call<ApiResponse<ApiData<Model>>> getData();` or `Call<ApiResponse<ApiData<? extends Model>>> getData();` doesn't work. Obviously, I have no strong consolidation of how generics work. An explanation would be nice.

Comment: Um ok. Looks like some of the irrelevant parts might be causing the trouble. I'm pretty sure I would find out what's the problem if I saw the actual code, this is just layers of abstraction resulting in us wasting our time on your bounty.

Comment: All the code I use is in the `EDITED` part of the answer. Time is money friend, so please don't waste yours on my bounty!

Comment: OK, one more edit, now this might work, but seriously, it feels like peeling an onion. Layer after layer, and almost makes you wanna cry, damn.

Comment: I tried both of these as an input to the `ApiClient#getData` method. Nor of these works. By the way why `ApiResponse<Data<? super Model>` and not `ApiResponse<Data<? extends Model>`, since the generic of Data can be either a `Model`, a `SubmodelA` or a `SubmodelB` ? I tried so many combinations that i start to believe that this is not doable. Nor it's useful anymore but it triggered my curiosity and I thought that it's a good chance for me to understand generics better.

Comment: Not sure what exactly the "doesn't work" part means. I guess the compiler error is gone, but something else is wrong. The `<? super Model>` should work because a more generic listener that accepts even `Object` should be able to listen to just anything, the `<? extends Model>` won't work, because listener of `SubModelA` shouldn't listen to `SubModelB` as it would be confused by the input and cast a `ClassCastException` at runtime, if you made it compile somehow.

Comment: One more thing: Inheritance in DTOs will cause you more harm than good. I don't like this `SubModelA` and `SubModelB` idea. More trouble than it's worth. So, the HTTP endpoint returns different model in different calls to the same resource? Can you somehow merge it into one unsightly model?

Comment: It can be merged, yes. As I already said, this use case is no longer used. The reason that I started the bounty was so I can understand WHY this doesn't work and also to get a better idea of generics.